# Can anyone tell me what the key shortcut is in Ubuntu 14.04 to activate/use scale/expo?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I am wondering if the keyshortcuts change in ubuntu 14.04...and wondering what they will be for scale and expo. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the settings in `ccsm`?

Comment: @terdon no. I am using linux mint now....I am installing ubuntu tomorrow...the moment it is released.

Comment: Hang on, so you haven't actually installed it and have no idea _if_ they will change? What's the point of asking then? They will probably be exactly the same as in all previous releases, why would they change? Anyway, you can use the solution in my answer to set them to whatever you like.

Comment: Sorry....I think my OP is wrong. I wanted to know where/how to change it. I kinda had the idea that it was in the ccsm...but wasnt sure. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ccsm` is the compiz-config-settings-manager, it can be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

This is where the `compiz` settings can be configured. So, just open it, either from the dash or by running `ccsm`, go into the scale or expo applet settings and choose your keybindings.

Answer (score 0):

A list of the short cut keys can be found already on your Ubuntu system.

To find this list of short keys, you need to take your mouse pointer to the top right hand side of your screen and click on the icon that looks like a gear with a line running half way through it.

- Once you have clicked that icon a pop down menu will appear.
- On that pop down menu, second from the top should be a menu item titled *"Ubuntu Help"* Select that menu item by clicking on it.
- A window will appear titled "Ubuntu Desktop Guide"

When observing this window you may notice that it represents or looks like some web browsers but without the icons and tabs at the top.

In the search bar at the top of that window I recommend that you type `Keyboard Shortcuts` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Once this has been done, you will be presented with a number of titles regarding keyboard shortcuts...

The titles that will interest you include:

- Useful keyboard shortcuts
- Set Keyboard Shortcuts